# Django database with ForeignKey and Fixture

Tags: mysql, database, django, foreign-keys, django-fixtures

I am trying to implement a restaurant chief website.

So basically, I have States, Cities, Restaurants and Chiefs.

```
Class State(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

Class City(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   state = models.ForeignKey(State)

class Restaurant(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   state = models.ForeignKey(City)

class Chief(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
```

Rules:

- States and city relations are fixed. A city cannot move to another state. But new states and city may be added.
- A restaurant can move to another city.
- A chief can move to another restaurant.
- A restaurant can have more than one chiefs.

1) Is this a correct model?

2) I upload some of the data via admin form, and some from fixtures, but sometimes when I need to change a Chief to another restaurant in a different state it causes problem when I try to view the website (**manage.py loaddata fixture** works fine) . But there is no problem with changing to a different restaurant within the same city.

I am open to any practical MySQL/Django book suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by "causes problems"? Is there some specific exception? How are you changing the Chief to a different restaurant?

Comment: It was giving some problems. I deleted the database, and created it from scratch again. Seems fine now.